# Can't add authorization header in Vue interceptors

Tags: vuejs2, vue-resource

I'm trying to add the Authorization token in requests headers with interceptors, but it's not working. The function that I push inside interceptors not run.

I add in my main.js the following code, but the code inside the function never runs

```
Vue.http.interceptors.push(function (request, next) {
  console.log('Interceptors')
  console.log(request)
  request.headers.set('Authorization', 'Bearer eyJ..kPw')
  request.headers.set('Accept', 'application/json')
  next()
})
```

I logged the *Vue.http.interceptors* and shows this:

```
["before", "method", "body", "jsonp", "header", "cors"]
```

But I can't figure out why the pushed function not works.

That is my main.js

```
import { sync } from 'vuex-router-sync'

import Vue from 'vue'
import Vuex from 'vuex'
import VueResource from 'vue-resource'
import VueRouter from 'vue-router'

Vue.use(Vuex)
Vue.use(VueResource)
Vue.use(VueRouter)

import App from './App'
import routes from './router'
import VuexStore from './vuex/store'

Vue.http.options.root = process.env.SERVER
console.log(Vue.http.interceptors)
Vue.http.interceptors.push(function (request, next) {
console.log('Interceptors')
console.log(request)
request.headers.set('Authorization', 'Bearer eyJ..kPw')
request.headers.set('Accept', 'application/json')
next()
})
Vue.config.productionTip = false

const store = new Vuex.Store(VuexStore)
const router = new VueRouter({
   routes
 })

sync(store, router)

/* eslint-disable no-new */
new Vue({
   el: '#app',
   router,
   template: '<App/>',
   components: { App }
})
```

Comment: Can we see more of your main.js? I don't see anything wrong with this specifically.

Comment: I will add to the question to be more readable

Comment: I'm not sure what's wrong in your case. I can take your exact interceptor and it works. https://codepen.io/Kradek/pen/xdZLbQ?editors=1010

Comment: Totally my fault.
I was practicing about Promises and use a ajax request instead of use the vue-resource http call. The interceptor doesn't work, cause there wasn't any call to intercept.

Comment: Hate it when that happens :) Glad you found it.